# SaxonApiException: The context item for axis step ./CLIENT is absent

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to convert and XML to an XML using XSLT 2.0 in saxon/java. I am using a sample XML I found on stack overflow  thread "Applying Muenchian grouping for a simple XML with XSLT"

However I am getting an error :  XPDY0002: The context item for axis step ./CLIENT is absent.

My test XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="CLIENTS" name="main">
<CLIENTS>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="CLIENT" group-by="NAME">
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>         </xsl:comment>
    <CLIENT>
      <xsl:sequence select="NAME" />
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <ACCOUNT>
          <xsl:sequence select="*[not(self::NAME)]" />
        </ACCOUNT>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </CLIENT>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </CLIENTS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Test XML:

```
<CLIENTS>
 <CLIENT>
<NAME>John</NAME>
<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>1424763562761</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
<LAST_USED>2012-10-03</LAST_USED>
<AMOUNT>5000</AMOUNT>
</CLIENT>
<CLIENT>
<NAME>John</NAME>
<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>543667543732</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
<LAST_USED>2012-10-02</LAST_USED>
<AMOUNT>10000</AMOUNT>
</CLIENT>
</CLIENTS>
```

My Java ( which works with other transforms) :

```
void xmlXSLTParser(){

String xslFile = commonPath + "/xslt/inputPointCSVTOXML_style2.xsl";
String inputFile = "file:///" + commonPath + pointWorkFile;
String outputFile = commonPath + pointWorkFile + ".final";

try {
    Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(new StreamSource(new   File(xslFile)));
    Serializer out = new Serializer();
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
    out.setOutputFile(new File(outputFile));

    XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();
    trans.setInitialTemplate(new QName("main"));
    //trans.setParameter(new QName("url-of-csv"),new  XdmAtomicValue(inputFile));
    trans.setDestination(out);
    trans.transform();

    System.out.println("Output written to text file");
} catch (SaxonApiException e) {
    println("XSLT Error :" + e );
}
}

}
```

My Error in detail:

```
Error at char 6 in xsl:for-each-group/@select on line 10 column 59 of    inputPointCSVTOXML_style2.xsl:

XPDY0002: The context item for axis step ./CLIENT is absent
XSLT Error :net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: The context item for      axis step ./CLIENT is absent
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Java code does not set any context item, instead it sets an initial template. So you will need to make sure you provide the input XML as the context item to the `XsltTransformer`, using http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltTransformer.html#setInitialContextNode(net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmNode) or as a `Source`, using http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltTransformer.html#setSource(javax.xml.transform.Source).

So instead of `trans.setInitialTemplate(new QName("main"));` use `trans.setSource(new StreamSource(inputFile));`.