# Saxonica - .NET API - XQuery - XPDY0002: The context item for axis step root/descendant::xxx is absent

Tags: saxon

I'm getting same error as this question, but with XQuery:
[SaxonApiException: The context item for axis step ./CLIENT is absent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063455/saxonapiexception-the-context-item-for-axis-step-client-is-absent)

When running from the command line, all is good.  So I don't think there is a syntax problem with the XQuery itself.  I won't post the input file unless needed.

The XQuery is displayed with a Console.WriteLine before the error appears:

```
----- Start: XQUERY:
(:  FLWOR = For Let Where Order-by Return   :)
<MyFlightLegs>
{
for $flightLeg in //FlightLeg
where $flightLeg/DepartureAirport = 'OKC' or $flightLeg/ArrivalAirport = 'OKC'
order by $flightLeg/ArrivalDate[1] descending
return $flightLeg
}
</MyFlightLegs>

----- End  : XQUERY:
Error evaluating (<MyFlightLegs {for $flightLeg in root/descendant::FlightLeg[DepartureAirport = "OKC" or ArrivalAirport = "OKC"] ... return $flightLeg}/>) on line 4 column 20
  XPDY0002: The context item for axis step root/descendant::FlightLeg is absent
```

I think that like the other question, maybe my input XML file is not properly specified.

I took the samples/cs/ExamplesHE.cs run method of the XQuerytoStream class.

Code there for easy reference is:

```
public class XQueryToStream : Example
{

    public override string testName
    {
        get { return "XQueryToStream"; }
    }

    public override void run(Uri samplesDir)
    {
        Processor processor = new Processor();
        XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
        compiler.BaseUri = samplesDir.ToString();
        compiler.DeclareNamespace("saxon", "http://saxon.sf.net/");
        XQueryExecutable exp = compiler.Compile("<saxon:example>{static-base-uri()}</saxon:example>");
        XQueryEvaluator eval = exp.Load();
        Serializer qout = processor.NewSerializer();
        qout.SetOutputProperty(Serializer.METHOD, "xml");
        qout.SetOutputProperty(Serializer.INDENT, "yes");
        qout.SetOutputStream(new FileStream("testoutput.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
        Console.WriteLine("Output written to testoutput.xml");
        eval.Run(qout);
    }

}
```

I changed to pass the Xquery file name, the xml file name, and the output file name, and tried to make a static method out of it. (Had success doing the same with the XSLT processor.)

```
static void DemoXQuery(string xmlInputFilename, string xqueryInputFilename, string outFilename)
{

    // Create a Processor instance.
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    // Load the source document
    DocumentBuilder loader = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
    loader.BaseUri = new Uri(xmlInputFilename);
    XdmNode indoc = loader.Build(loader.BaseUri);

    XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
    //BaseUri is inconsistent with Transform= Processor? 
    //compiler.BaseUri = new Uri(xqueryInputFilename);
    //compiler.DeclareNamespace("saxon", "http://saxon.sf.net/");

    string xqueryFileContents = File.ReadAllText(xqueryInputFilename);
    Console.WriteLine("----- Start: XQUERY:");
    Console.WriteLine(xqueryFileContents);
    Console.WriteLine("----- End  : XQUERY:");
    XQueryExecutable exp = compiler.Compile(xqueryFileContents);
    XQueryEvaluator eval = exp.Load(); 

    Serializer qout = processor.NewSerializer();
    qout.SetOutputProperty(Serializer.METHOD, "xml");
    qout.SetOutputProperty(Serializer.INDENT, "yes");
    qout.SetOutputStream(new FileStream(outFilename, 
                 FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));

    eval.Run(qout);

}
```

Also two questions regarding "BaseURI".
1. Should it be a directory name, or can it be same as the Xquery file name? 
2. I get this compile error: "Cannot implicity convert to "System.Uri" to "String".

```
compiler.BaseUri = new Uri(xqueryInputFilename);
```

It's exactly the same thing I did for XSLT which worked. But it looks like BaseUri is a string for XQuery, but a real Uri object for XSLT?  Any reason for the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking a whole series of separate questions, which are hard to disentangle.

Your C# code appears to be compiling the query

```
<saxon:example>{static-base-uri()}</saxon:example>
```

which bears no relationship to the XQuery code you supplied that involves `MyFlightLegs`.

The `MyFlightLegs` query uses `//FlightLeg` and is clearly designed to run against a source document containing a `FlightLeg` element, but your C# code makes no attempt to supply such a document. You need to add an `eval.ContextItem = value` statement.

Your second C# fragment creates an input document in the line

```
XdmNode indoc = loader.Build(loader.BaseUri);
```

but it doesn't supply it to the query evaluator.

A base URI can be either a directory or a file; resolving `relative.xml` against `file:///my/dir/` gives exactly the same result as resolving it against `file:///my/dir/query.xq`. By convention, though, the static base URI of the query is the URI of the resource (eg file) containing the source query text.

Yes, there's a lot of inconsistency in the use of strings versus URI objects in the API design. (There's also inconsistency about the spelling of `BaseURI` versus `BaseUri`.) Sorry about that; you're just going to have to live with it.

Comment: In C# I think it is a property assignment `eval.ContextItem = indoc;`, not a `SetContextItem()` call.

Comment: Thanks, In C#, the solution was "eval.ContextItem = indoc; ".  The first C# code was your sample that I tried to model after.  I see now that it didn't have an input file.  But now I see other examples XQueryToDom and XQueryToXdm that use the .ContextItem property.

Comment: To get the baseURI to work I had to do this: compiler.BaseUri = xqueryInputFilename.Replace(@"\","/");  as per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005859/saxon-8-xquery-file-java-call to avoid the error "Illegal character in opaque part" in java.net.URISyntaxException.

Comment: Yes, it's a URI, not a filename.URIs never contain backslashes. In fact, just converting the backslashes to forwards slashes isn't enough, you also need to deal with special characters such as spaces and '#'.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks, I corrected it to set the ContextItem property.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line solution based on Michael Kay's response; I added this line of code after doing the exp.Load():

```
eval.ContextItem = indoc;
```

The indoc object created earlier is what relates to the XML input file to be processed by the XQuery.